# Plan B, or what's the opposite of Maybe's >>=?

Tags: haskell, option-type

Let's take two functions:

```
f :: a -> Maybe b
g :: b -> Maybe c
```

The function `>>=` would work in such a way that `f >>= g` would execute `g` with the result of `f` only if it's not `Nothing`. In other words, it requires both `f` and `g` to succeed to produce any result.

I'm implementing a parser and realized that my lexer would benefit from somewhat the opposite of this. That is:

```
f :: a -> Maybe b
g :: a -> Maybe b

planb :: (a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> Maybe b)
planb f g = \x -> case f x of
                      Nothing -> g x
                      res -> res
```

which means try `f` and if it fails, try `g` as a backup plan. With a lexer it means try to match a token type with the current input and if it failed, try to match another token type (which would eventually be chained for all token types).

Searching Hoogle didn't result in any such function, but to me such a function seems to be useful in many places!

My question is thus, whether a variant of `planb` exists already that I should be using? If not, am I doing something extraordinary and there is a better way to achieve what I want?

---

P.S. I thought about whether such a function makes sense for `Monad`s in general, but it doesn't make that much sense to me outside `Maybe` and perhaps a few others.

Comment: Sound like you look for [`MonadPlus`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MonadPlus).

Comment: @Franky you should make that an answer.

Comment: BTW I do not see a reason for a lambda here. `planb f g x = case f x...` works. Maybe the (unnecessary) parenthesis around the rightmost `a -> Maybe b` obscured your sight. Maybe it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: @Franky, actually I put the last parentheses (and used a lambda in the definition) to emphasize that `f \`planb\` g` creates a new function, much like `g . f` or `g <=< f` does

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `Alternative` typeclass does precisely this, it is quite similar to `MonadPlus` but perhaps a bit more general.

```hs
import Control.Applicative

-- most general form
planb :: (Applicative g, Alternative f) => g (f a) -> g (f a) -> g (f a)
planb = liftA2 (<|>)

-- specialized to (->) and Maybe
planb' :: (a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> Maybe b)
planb' = planb

-- equivalent to planb' (and planb) but without the fancy combinators
planb'' :: (a -> Maybe b) -> (a -> Maybe b) -> a -> Maybe b
planb'' f g x = f x <|> g x
```

Plugging this in to a simple test case:

```
test :: Maybe Int
test = do
  a <- planb' (const Nothing) id (Just 1)
  b <- planb' id id (Just 1)
  c <- planb' id (const Nothing) (Just 1)
  return $ a + b + c
```

Generates the expected result:

```
*Main> test
Just 3
```

Comment: I hadn't paid attention that lift can be used to add `a ->` to a type. It's both intriguing and weird that `(->) r` is also a Monad (, Applicative and Functor). While the other answer would be simpler, I'll go with yours so I'll learn it better through experience. Thanks!

Comment: No perhaps about it, `Alternative` will become a superclass of `MonadPlus` in the great GHC 7.10 AMP shakeup.

Comment: Link to the haskellwiki page about the Applicative Monad Proposal (AMP) [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal)

Answer (score 6):

Note that your `planb` function really only needs to operate on `Maybe` values; calling the functions to produce them can be factored out.

```
planb :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
planb Nothing b = b
planb a _ = a
```

And you'd call it like `planb (f x) (g x)` to get a `Maybe` result.

With that in mind, take a look at the [`MonadPlus` class](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/ghc-doc/libraries/haskell2010-1.1.1.0/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus) (as suggested by [Franky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412549/franky) in a comment):

```
planb = mplus
```

You might also be interested in `msum`, which takes a list of `Maybe` values and returns the first one (if any) that isn't `Nothing`.  Here's a handy function:

```
matchSomehow :: [a -> Maybe b] -> a -> Maybe b
matchSomehow fs a = msum $ map ($a) fs
```

Comment: Defining `planb` like that means I couldn't write something like this anymore: `testAll = testThis \`planb\` testThat \`planb\` testHere \`planb\` testThere`, but I would have to apply the function argument to every single one of them. Very good point with the last one though, `testAll = planb [testThis, testThat, testHere, testThere]` would work (and I don't have to write the fold as I would with the `Alternative` answer!

Comment: Instead of writing the fold yourself, you can use [`Data.Foldable.asum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum) for `Alternative` just like this answer uses `msum` for MonadPlus.